# Is there a clash between TMMATHS and MTPRO2?

Tags: fonts

I have the TM-Math (Micropress) and MTPRO2 (PCTeX) fonts installed on my systems (TeXLive for Linux; MikTeX for Windows) and I recently typeset some integrals using the TM-Math fonts via the 'tmmaths' package. For some reason the limits on the integral are positioned as though it expected the integral symbol to be slanted rather than upright, as it is in the TM-Math set. So my question is whether there is some sort of clash between these two font sets? Does anyone else have both fonts on their system and can still manage to get an upright integral with properly positioned limits?

Comment: This is unclear as-is. If you can compose a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), the question could be a candidate for re-opening.